# mysql GROUP BY products

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

```
table:
id   p_name      p_price
1    tan           1
2    soap          1
3    pro tan 01    2 
4    pro tan 02    3 
5    pro tan 03    4
```

How do I group the products that contain `pro tan`, something what I want for the html result

```
product name     price
tan                1
soap               1
pro tan            9
```

php:

```
$q_products = $db->query("SELECT * FROM p_products 
                          GROUP BY p_name 
                          HAVING LIKE 'pro tan%'"); 
// follow by while loop for echoing
```

Comment: You could select the first 7 characters of the productname column and group by that substring, that will work for this sample data, but may break when other productnames are entered in the table...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select s.p_name, sum(s.p_price) 
from 
  (select left(p_name, 7) as p_name, 
   p_price from products) s
group by s.p_name;
```

should do what you want.

Comment: Are you sure you tried this one? Above you have `having LIKE 'pro tan%'` when it should be `having p_name LIKE 'pro tan%'`

Comment: What error did you get (I changed the query, since it grouped by the complete p_name, not only the first 7 characters as requested by you)?

Comment: @Frank You were missing an alias on your inner select, I edited the code (visible after peer review) to show the correct code.

Comment: @Johan Thanks, I didn't have a MySQL database available to check it. How exactly does "visible after peer review" work?

Comment: @Frank Schmitt: You need a certain reputation score to be able to see that. I just approved it though, so now you can see what Johan changed :p.

Comment: @Frank, if you have a low-ish reputation you can edit stuff, but other people will only see your edits after it's been approved by someone with higher reputation. Your post was close, so I decided to edit it rather than add a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I cant comment yet, but try this

```
$q_products = $db->query("SELECT * FROM p_products GROUP BY p_name having p_name LIKE 'pro tan%'");
```